# SQL Server CE EF Optimization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have the following code which updates / adds data to a SQL Server CE database with EF6, which is working fine for small number of records. However when the volume of records exceeds 1000~2000 the transaction become very slow (10~15sec). Is there any way to optimize it?

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", "", MyProject.ConnectionString);

ProjectContext context = new ProjectContext();
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

using (var db = new ProjectContext())
{           
    foreach (var item in MyProject.Brands)
    {
        if (!db.Brands.Any(i => i.Name == item.Name))
        {
           // Add
           db.Brands.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
           // Update
           var found = db.Brands.First(i => i.Name == item.Name);
           found = item;
        }
    }

    db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Try building a dictionary of brand names instead of looking through all of them every single time. Failing that, use `FirstOrDefault` to get your hands on the `Brand` at the same time as figuring out whether it exists or not.

Comment: Also I'm not sure `found = item;` does what you think it does...

Comment: thanks for responce, I am not sure about the dictionary, since I was planning to extend the database transaction to 100000 records. By the way found is updating the row once it is found

Comment: You are not using `context` at all, so why define it? Since you are usign a new `ProjectContext` for your inserts/updates, your `MyProject.Brands` will be unknown to that context. The inserts will work, but the updates will not. Even more, you extract found from your new context, then you simply overwrite it with a non-attached `item` instead of actually updating the `found` item from your db. You can combine the two Linq queries in one, to save 50% on your queries, as ta.speot says.

Comment: I have some ideas here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/06/inserting-many-rows-with-entity.html

Answer (score 2):

This way you save 50% on your Linq queries, and your update might actually work (your `MyProject.Brands` are not attached in any way to your `new ProjectContext` that you are using, the `found` that you extract from there *is* attached, but in your original code, you overwrote it with yuor `item`, meaning it will be ignored.
`context` I have left out completely, as you were not doing anything with it, as your using creates a new `ProjectContext` anyway.

```
using (var db = new ProjectContext())
{           
    foreach (var item in MyProject.Brands)
    {
        var found = db.Brands.FirstOrdefault(i => i.Name == item.Name);
        if (found == null)
        {
           // Add
           db.Brands.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
           // Update
           found.prop1 = item.prop1;
           found.prop2 = item.prop2;
           // ... etc, for all and any updatable properties
        }
    }
    db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```